# Quiero hacer una validación con repetidor en C++

Tags: c++

Hola chic@s Nuevamente acudo a ustedes a ver si me pueden por favor de ayudar.
Quiero agregar un repetidor en esas validaciones para cuando ingreso lo que me piden si no es valido, me salga la advertencia y me deje volver a ingresarlo nuevamente hasta que el dato sea correcto para pasar a la siguiente.
Les agradecería mucho la ayuda de alguno de ustedes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Validar{
    public:
    Validar();// COSTRUCTOR
    void ValidarID();//METODOS
    void ValidarEdad();
    void ValidarSexo();
    void ValidarCodigoR();
};
Validar::Validar(){//CONSTRUCTOR PARA INICIALIZAR LAS CONDICIONES

}


void Validar::ValidarID(){ //VALIDAMOS QUE LA CEDULA TENGA MAS DE 7 DIJITOS DE LO CONTRARIO ERROR!!

    for (int i=1; i<=NConductores; i++){

        if(Cedula[i]>999999){
        }

        else {
            cout << " ¡¡¡ADVERTENCIA!!! ";
            cout << " UNA DE LAS CEDULAS INGRESADAS NO CUNPLE CON LOS PARAMETROS ESTABLECIDOS.";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}


void Validar::ValidarEdad(){//VALIDAMOS LA EDAD SIGUIENDO LAS NORMAS ESTABLECIDAS QUE SEAN MAYORES DE 16

    for (int i=1; i<=NConductores; i++){

        if(Edad[i]>=16){
        }

        else {
            cout << " ¡¡¡ADVERTENCIA!!! ";
            cout << " UNA DE LAS EDADES NO ESTA DENTRO DE LOS ESTANDARES ESTABLECIDOS";
            cout << " EN LAS NORMAS DE TRANSITO";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}


void Validar::ValidarSexo(){ //VALIDAMOS EL GENERO DEL USUARIO INGRESADO

    for (int i=1; i<=NConductores; i++){

        if(Sexo[i]==0 or Sexo[i]==1){
        }

        else {
            cout << " ¡¡¡ADVERTENCIA!!! ";
            cout << " OPCION NO VALIDA EN EL SEXO. ";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void Validar::ValidarCodigoR(){ //VALIDAMOS QUE LOS CODIGOS 1 Y 0 SEAN INGRESADOS CORRECTAMENTE.

    for (int i=1; i<=NConductores; i++){

        if(Codigo[i]==0 or Codigo[i]==1){
        }

        else {
            cout << " ¡¡¡ADVERTENCIA!!! ";
            cout << " CODIGO INVALIDO";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, es necesario poner la parte del código en texto para que otras personas puedan replicar tu problema y ayudarte; las preguntas con imágenes de código pueden no ser bien recibidas. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga mejor aceptación

Answer (score 0):

utiliza el do{} while para hacer eso, por ejemplo.

```
void Validar::ValidarSexo(){ //VALIDAMOS EL GENERO DEL USUARIO INGRESADO
bool sw=false;//declaras un flag
do {
    for (int i=1; i<=NConductores; i++){

        if(Sexo[i]==0 or Sexo[i]==1){
          sw=true;//cuando cumpla la condicion
        }

        else {
            cout << " ¡¡¡ADVERTENCIA!!! ";
            cout << " OPCION NO VALIDA EN EL SEXO. ";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
 }while(sw=false)//terminara cuando sea true
}
```